# Python File Upload to Google Cloud Storage Bucket return Broken Pipe Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, broken-pipe

I'm trying to upload a file to Google cloud storage Bucket using Python.It was working fine before but suddenly returning an error.

Here's my code:

**from views.py:**

```
def perform_upload(video, thumbnail):
    print('vdieo name is: {}'.format(video))
    servise = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    bucket_name = 'test_bucket004'
    print('Uploading the video...')
    media = MediaFileUpload(video, chunksize=4149304, mimetype='video/mp4',
                        resumable=True)
    req = servise.objects().insert(
        bucket=bucket_name,
        name=str(video),
        media_body=media,
        body={"cacheControl": "public,max-age=31536000"},
        predefinedAcl='publicRead'
    )
    resp = None
    while resp is None:
        status, resp = req.next_chunk()
    print(resp)
```

Here's what it returns:

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> [22/Sep/2018 04:56:50] "POST /api/convert/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15981

and Traceback pointing to this line:

```
  status, resp = req.next_chunk()
```

What can be wrong?
How can I resolve this Broken pipe error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you trying to upload the file from? Your local environment?

Comment: yes, from the local environment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your network connection (and thus, your connection to GCS) is unstable for some reason. I would recommend retrying this from an environment with a more stable internet connection (switching to a wired connection from wifi, removing an intermediate proxies or firewalls, etc).